# will two war with same package name under Tomcat interfere each other?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've a question that if I export a spring project twice, and give them different names, then deploy to the server(ex. Tomcat8), will these two web app interfere each other? (due to they're same project and having same package name) or will Tomcat deploy them in different scope and each of them can execute independently?

thank for any advise in advance!

Comment: The point of the complicated classloaders in application containers is specifically to manage this--but Spring Boot is nearly always a lot simpler approach.

Comment: Tomcat will deploy them with the names of their war files as their context (app) names. They will not interfere, if they have the same package names.